# Selecting the .index() of a deeply nested element

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested

I want to select the  tags onlu inside a  by the index shown in the link names. What is the best method of doing this?

```
<div class="index-get">
    <div class="column">
        <a href="#">Category Title</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Index 0</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Index 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

$('.index-get ul a').click(function(){

    var aIndex = $(this).index();
    console.log(aIndex);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the question is clear enough but here is something that might relate to what you need:

```
$('.index-get ul a').click(function(){
    var aIndex = $(this).text();
    console.log(aIndex);
});
```

And the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/RWSPN/).

**EDIT**

I think I finally got it the question **sigh**... :-)
Since there is only one A inside each parent LI the index of A tags will always be 0 in your example because the index is in relation to the sieblings...

If you calculate the index for the LI you might get better result. But keep in mind the index is only counted inside each parent so for the two ULs you will get two sets of LI children hence clicking Index 1 or Index 6 will yield the same result.

[New Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zbThS/)

**One more edit**

Actually the ULs are nor sieblings and one must go above to the DIV and down again into the ULs to be able to count the LI of previous items... But I guess it works just perfect for your needs. I I understood your needs that is... ;-)

```
$('.index-get ul li').click(function(){
    var aIndex = $(this).index()+$(this).parent().parent().prev().find("ul").children().length;
    console.log(aIndex);
});
```

And the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/PwFed/).

**Last edit**
Making the line slightly simpler

```
var aIndex = $(this).index() + $(this).parent().parent().prev().find("ul li").length;
```

- &(this) is an LI element.
- $(this).parent() is the UL
- $(this).parent().parent() is the DIV
- $(this).parent().parent().prev() are all the sibling elements of that DIV (hopefully only DIVs in there and all with the same type of content)
- $(this).parent().parent().prev().find("ul li") all LI inside UL inside sibling DIVs.
- $(this).parent().parent().prev().find("ul li").length; the number of LI in the previous line.

There you go. Simple logic! ;-)

**And when you think all is done and settled... There comes one more edit!!! :-)**

I was thinking of the solution I proposed and it will eventually fail if you have more then two UL groups and if you click on a LI located in the third UL or later.

Therefore I have created yet another solution which uses .prevAll() instead of just .prev() but then must use the .each() with a function to add up all the count of all LI elements from the previous ULs.

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WtjB5/1/)

Now I can go sleep in peace! :-)

Fabricio

Comment: Haha sorry I see what you did there! Unfortunately the Index 5 has index() of 0, instead of 4.

Comment: Yes. That's what I said would happen. But for that you will need to count all previous LI inside previous sibling ULs.

Comment: I could do that, although it doesn't feel like the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Well... I don't think you will manage it any other way without changing your HTML/CSS... :-/ See my last update. It seems to work nice.

Comment: Well that method works perfectly. The selector is insane though, just trying to get my head around it. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer! I was making an effort to pass 50 points and be able to comment on other questions to ask for clarifications instead of answering the question by guessing like I actually did with your at first... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 var aIndex = $('.index-get li a').index($(this));
```

and you should cache `$('.index-get li a')` outside of the event handler

```
var $lia = $('.index-get li a');

$lia.on('click',function() {

       console.log($lia.index($(this)));

    })
```

Comment: Can u explain me concept cache $('.index-get li a') outside event handler means?  +1 for this

Comment: it means you access the dom only once, you store the "a" in a jquery object that remains in the jquery cache then everytime the event is triggered your script access the jquery cache instead of the dom (faster) - ie if you use `$('li a')` in your handler, at every trigger your script access the dom (slower)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('.index-get ul a').click(function(){
    var aIndex = $(this).text().match(/\d+$/)[0];
    console.log(aIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work no matter how deep the li's are nested:

```js
var items = $('li');

items.on('click', function() {
  var clicked_item = $(this);
  
  items.each(function(index){
    if ($(this).is(clicked_item)){
      console.log(index);
    } 
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="index-get">
    <div class="column">
        <a href="#">Category Title</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Index 0</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Index 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Index 9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```